# rails 3 observe_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-2

I'm upgrading rails_2 project to rails_3. Have a problem with loading data into view from :(
old environtment: rails 2.3.2, ruby 1.8.7
now : rails 3.2.11, ruby 1.9.3

I have a form_for @lead and observe_form in view

{ :action => :update_price }, :frequency => 0.1 %>

but when I run rails server, I see empty page in browser :(

Comment: <%= form_for %> Have you added "=" in the form tag???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<%= form_for %> Have you added "=" in the form tag??? – Sachin R